# CakePHP: How to efficiently enforce unique join table records

Tags: php, cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm using CakePHP 2.x and I frequently run into situations where I want to add records to a join table, but I want to make sure the same "join" record does not already exist.

For concreteness, here's a basic example...

Model: Student hasAndBelongsToMany Course(s)
Model: Course hasAndBelongsToMany Student(s)
Join Table = courses_students and has fields "student_id" and "course_id"

Let's say I have a form with a bunch of students that I want to associate with a course. The form submits a bunch of student_id(s) to the controller. Before I add the new records, I need to make sure the records don't already exist (because you can't enroll for the same course twice). This is where things get messy...

Option 1: I sometimes build a deleteAll() for every (possibly) pre-existing record in the join table that has the current course_id and any of the submitted user_id(s). This is efficient, but the downside is that it erases any pre-existing data that may have been stored in other fields, such as the date etc.

Option 2: I sometimes loop over each of the submitted records and do a find() for each (possibly) pre-existing record. This allows me to preserve existing records, but makes a bunch of extra queries to the DB.

These are the two ways I typically handle this situation, but I suspect there is a better way. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REPLACE INTO`. For example:

```
REPLACE INTO courses_students (course_id, student_id, when)
  VALUES (1, 2, 12345678)
```

Which would overwrite column `when` with the new value. I'm sure there's a way to not do that in pure SQL though: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Also not sure how that would work in CakePHP. Their DBAL probably has a helper for db merges.

(MySQL doesn't support `MERGE INTO .. WHEN MATCHED`, so you'll have to do a SELECT and then INSERT anyway.)

(Btw: option 2 isn't inefficient, because you'll have created a composite, unique key for `course_id` + `student_id`. The `SELECT` will be super fast.)

**edit**
`SELECT`s are very, very fast and cheap if you index your columns correctly. Table `courses_students` should have a PK on `(course_id, student_id)`. You can do all the SELECTs in 1 query, if you're worried about the number of queries:

```
:ids from input
SELECT course_id, student_id FROM courses_students WHERE course_id IN (:ids) AND student_id IN (:ids)
```

And then map them to an assoc accessible array:

```
array(course_id => array(student_id => TRUE))
```

And then loop through the input (POST?) and filter existing records:

```
if ( !isset($map[$course_id][$student_id]) ) {
  // INSERT HERE
}
```

For a total of `count(INPUT) + 1` queries.

But all of that is a lot of code. You can just loop and query per record. I promise it's cheap.

Comment: What you said is informative but I'm trying to stick with CakePHP conventions and avoid writing raw queries. Although I don't fully understand the last thing you said. How is it possible for looping over hundreds of items and making a SELECT call for each one not inefficient? Aren't these kinds of n* operations almost the definition of inefficiency?

Comment: A SELECT query that only queries indexed fields (primary key probably) is super fast. The socket is probably a UNIX socket, not a TCP socket, so that's super fast too. There's hardly any data transfer, so that's super fast too. 100s of queries is not necessarily bad =) (I can't find a MERGE or REPLACE db helper for CakePHP. Where's CakePHP's db API reference??)

Comment: I think this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html or this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html is the closest thing to what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I found that. Too tutorial-ish. Not very api reference-ish. So no CakePHP merge function. Sorry. SELECT + INSERT is your best bet. Probably more efficient than DELETE + INSERT. Definitely if you can do the SELECTs in 1 query. See answer.